# Terraform resource "aws_ecr_repository_policy" always wants to be updated in version 1.5.7

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using `"terraform-aws-modules/ecr/aws"` in nested module with Terraform version 1.5.7

provider.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.5.7"

  backend "s3" {
    ...
  }
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.37"
    }
  }
}
```

ecr.tf

```
module "my_ecr" {
  source = "../shared/ecr"
  .....
}
```

shared/ecr/main.tf

```
module "ecr" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ecr/aws"
  ...
}
```

When i run terraform plan with this code, module.ecr.aws_ecr_repository_policy.this[0] always wants to be changed. (i don't have any changed resource or terraform code.)

```
module.my_ecr.module.ecr.aws_ecr_repository_policy.this[0] will be updated in-place

  ~ resource "aws_ecr_repository_policy" "this" {
        id          = "example"
      ~ policy      = jsonencode(
          ~ {
              ~ Statement = [
                    {
                        Action    = [
                            "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
                            "ecr:ListImages",
                            "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                            "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
                            "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
                            "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                            "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                            "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                            "ecr:DescribeImages",
                            "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings",
                            "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                            "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                        ]
                        Effect    = "Allow"
                        Principal = {
                            AWS = "arn:aws:iam::....."
                        }
                        Sid       = "PrivateReadOnly"
                    },
                  - {
                      - Action    = [
                          - "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                          - "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                          - "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
                          - "ecr:DeleteRepositoryPolicy",
                          - "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                        ]
                      - Condition = {
                          - StringLike = {
                              - "aws:sourceArn" = "arn:aws:lambda:...."
                            }
                        }
                      - Effect    = "Allow"
                      - Principal = {
                          - Service = "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                        }
                      - Sid       = "LambdaECRImageRetrievalPolicy"
                    },
                ]
                # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
            }
        )
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Why is this happening?

I tried to change terraform version, but it did not worked

Comment: is your Terraform code controlled by any SCM?

Comment: Which provider version are you using?

Comment: I use github & github action to plan (when i push on branch) and apply (when i merge branch) @MohammedEhab

Comment: I'm using version 5.38.0 @MarkoE

Comment: Well, it seems someone might have changed the policy outside terraform, and it's getting reset to what was defined in the code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked on AWS console, but `LambdaECRImageRetrievalPolicy` still exists on AWS (there was no changes)..

Comment: As mentioned, it might exist in the console, but it might not exist in the actual terraform code, hence the difference.

Comment: Please provide the terraform code of `resource "aws_ecr_repository_policy" "this"`

Answer (score 0):

check the difference in the commit history. Even though the policy JSON itself hasn't changed, if there are any whitespace or formatting changes (like indentation) in your Terraform files or the JSON itself, Terraform might interpret it as a change.

also check for dependency changes. If there are any dependencies of the aws_ecr_repository_policy resource that have changed (even if they seem unrelated), it might trigger Terraform to detect a change in this resource.

If possible, try running terraform apply to see if the plan still shows the same change. Sometimes, it might be a false positive in the plan but I actually doubt that.